# Ghost Cleanup process has high CPU usage in SQL Server 2012 SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ghost-cleanup

Has anyone encountered this?  We are using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition with SP1.  During a time of low/no activity, I noticed the Ghost Cleanup process is utilizing CPU at a very high rate, from 75% to 99%, these aren't bursts but sustained usage.

I don't see the ghost cleanup process blocking itself, it just seems to take a lot of CPU while it runs, and never seems to complete.  How can I tell if it's actually doing something?

Is this a bug with SQL Server 2012?  I have seen this in SQL 2008 and there was [a fix for it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978430) but I haven't seen anything for 2012.

Comment: Any data deletion happening e.g. deleting large amount of LOB data, etc ? See this blog post http://michaeljswart.com/2017/08/problem-with-too-many-version_ghost_records/ . Also, you should be atleast on sp4- 11.0.7001.0 version. Please patch sql server and see if you still encounter issues with Ghost Clenaup or not.